# Sql sum value subtract by user input in asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, inventory-management

I am trying to develop Inventory System. I created 3 tables **Product**,**Supplier** and **Purchase**.

`Product`

- productId(PK)
- productName

`Supplier`

- SupplierId(Pk)
- CompanyName

`Purchase`

- PurchaseId(PK)
- ProductId(FK)
- SupplierId(FK)

To show my available stock (Product Name,Company Name and Quantity), I execute a query:

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[GroupByTotalStock]
as
begin
select Product.ProductName,Supplier.CompanyName, Sum(Purchase.Quantity) as total
from Product 
inner join Purchase on Product.ProductId = Purchase.ProductId
inner join Supplier on Purchase.SupplierId = Supplier.SupplierId
group by product.ProductName, Supplier.CompanyName
end
```

[image: Query Result]

I need to add another field **Sales** where i want to display query result data to gridview and search field to search my product information (Product name, company name, Quantity). Then retrieved those data from gridview to text field.

[image: My design screenshot]

Now my questions are:

- How can i subtract (which i sell, it is user input) my product total quantity by group wise?
- What would be the query or logic ?

I will also create a table where stored sales information.

Comment: If you need help with a query, then you should show us the expected output.

Comment: In my above query result there are total 14 quantity in productname="mango" and Companyname="BAT"
See in my design screenshot, if i sell (for example: 5,what user will give) the same product of same company, the amount of total quantity will be decrease by the calculation of Available qunatity- sell quantity.
My expected output will be 14-5= 9.
Thanks

Comment: where is your `sale` table?

Comment: do you want to display the remaining stock after sales before it is stored in the database or after the insert of the sales quantity?

Comment: Simply call your SP, get the result, search the product and company name in it locally with Linq. Once you have found it, you have the "total" avail in stock. You can then do a simple subtraction.

Comment: A more direct way would to use Linq to get the available total for a given product and company. You really didn't need such an SP.

Comment: @Lmu92 i want to display the remaining stock after sales and after it is stored in the database. Actually when i save, i want to update the **total** of `Purchase.Quantity` table according to my product name and company name.
Thanks.

Comment: . @TimBiegeleisen I need help with a update query. In above i explain my expected output.
Thanks.

Comment: @ Kaushik, you may also try to create View Table which will have Columns for Product_Name, Product_Id and Quantity_Purchase from "Purchase Table" and Product_Name, Product_ID (as Common field), and Quantity_Sold from "Sale Table" and you can subtract the Sum of Quantity_Sold with the Sum of Quantity_Purchase aligned according to their Product_Id and get the value in another column as StockInHand in the same View Table. Then when you search for the product your query will go through this View table and bind the data into your Grid View. If anything more to be done, please ping me.